# File storage for social media application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mobile-application, file-storage

I am launching Mobile application with backend as PHP hosted on 4 instances of AWS Elastic beanstalk. For media storage (images and videos) I am not sure if S3 is a better option or having an EC2 instance with a share directory will be fine.

My consideration will be based on performance and throughput. For S3 i never came across any documentation or reference which can give me the throughput between EC2 and S3.

Comment: By Throughput means what you wanted to know?

Comment: Means data transfer speed

Answer (score 0):

As per your use case S3 is the best option as per the images durability goes. And the data transfer speeds between an EC2 instance and S3 is super fast so you don't have to worry about that.

And if you come across issue where there is latency in data transferred between the EC2 instance and S3 due to the Instance and S3 bucket regions being different AWS just introduced S3 Accelerated transfer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html

So using S3 for image file storage is most durable and reliable option for your use case.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. few quick ones, Is it going to be the case of mounting a drive to each of my instance which will be S3?

If so, which tool is recommended to use for this purpose in production env?